# How can I remedy incorrect answers to interview questions after the fact?

Tags: united-kingdom, interviewing

After completing an interview with a potential employer, I sometimes realize that I either misunderstood a question in the heat of the moment, or I simply didn't know the answer to it.

When I later realize or learn the answer, what can I do to remedy the situation? Do I have any options to overcome this slip-up?

Comment: The French call it _esprit d'escalier_, I believe.

Comment: wouldn't bother tbh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you provided an incorrect answer to a technical question on an interview, should you respond with a corrected answer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9328/if-you-provided-an-incorrect-answer-to-a-technical-question-on-an-interview-sho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop them a line with the correct answers, of course. And they might pick up on the fact that you researched things after the fact and got back to them with correct answers later on.

(For what it's worth, I might in some circumstances -- namely if the questions were really complex. In that case you'd get bonus points for being curious enough to verify that you were right or wrong, bonus point for being humble enough to highlight that you were wrong and come back with the correct answer, and yet more bonus points for showing motivation for the job.)

That said, more often than not that a company will have decided to not hire you then and there if they were very unsatisfied with your answers. In that case there's really nothing you can do...