# Sending a second follow-up e-mail to an incorrectly answered interview question

Tags: interviewing, new-job

[Here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9376/52645) Fecak states to send an e-mail discussing the correct answer over the incorrect answer given in the interview, which I already did. I received a favorable response. [Another answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49008/how-can-i-remedy-incorrect-answers-to-interview-questions-after-the-fact) advises the same process.

I answered 20 questions from several particular topics (about 6) in the technical portion of the interview. I answered two questions incorrectly, to which one I already sent an e-mail about (see above). I did not answer two other interview questions, and gave an "I don't know/I've never seen that before" response. But the second interview question I answered incorrectly I am now just realizing I answered incorrectly and I want to send the interviewer another e-mail detailing my correct responses to the incorrectly answered question and the questions I did not know an answer to.

What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Comment: One email is kinda pushing it. A second email may sound like desparation and will raise questions like "how many tries will this dude need to get it right ?" So, my opinion, take your losses and chalk it up as learning experience. Who knows, with your wrong/missing answers, you may sound like someone honest, over another BS artist.

Comment: How long ago since your last response? A day, or two? If it's more than a few days I would just continue with the job hunt as they are not interested in you.

Comment: @Dan: Yesterday was my interview. They said 1 or 2 weeks.

Comment: @MelBurslan Sorry, no - [see this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9376/52645)

Comment: @JossieCalderon Honestly I would just take Mel advice and simply move on. It was an honest mistake. 18/20 doesn't sound too bad. Someone ought to know everyone can't know everything.

Comment: @JossieCalderon That answer, as much as supports your approach, and rated highly, is opinion based. And my opinion is, against that answer. Sorry.

Comment: @Dan Should I move on if they said "1 or 2 weeks" because they have interviewed three, still need a few more interviews, and then they'll make a decision? There are two positions available.

Comment: @JossieCalderon From my experience the follow up email never worked. I say go ahead and do it if you feel it'll improve your chances. It may work and you may get lucky. As I said 18/20 isn't bad at all so you might already be favored.

Comment: @Dan I feel as if I did well on my interview. We'll just have to wait for the verdict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would advise you not to send multiple e-mails as it is looked down upon. Sending the 1 or 2 you have already is fine (i.e. a thank you note and your answer elaboration/correction), but anything more could be looked upon as pestering/desperate. Ideally, communication is kept to an appropriate minimal to avoid disturbing the hiring manager and putting a negative connotation on your name while still keeping in touch.

Answering something wrong is not the end of the world in an interview and replying back to one of the incorrect answers you gave shows you thought about the issue, gave an answer upfront when requested, kept working on the issue, found the correct answer, and finally provided the correct answer. It is a good trait potentially as well as bad one (i.e. overthinks things even after making a decision on them). You do not want to be seen as rethinking ALL of your answers as then you come across as potentially incompetent or unable to "think on your feet".

Saying "I don't know" or "I have never come across that particular scenario" shows honesty and integrity in most situations. Most hiring managers are happy to hear the honest answer then an answer where the candidate "BS'ed" or stumbled his/her way through without admitting he/she doesn't know. If it is only a question or two then it is fine, but if it is a lot more then it shows you may not have the skills for the job (or that you require a lot of training). Keep in mind that technical questions upon which you should be proficient in should not receive an "I don't know" answer (i.e. an Accounting Manager candidate saying "I don't know how to prepare financial reports" is a red flag for the hiring manager).

A good strategy for questions where you do not know the answer but do not want to sound completely inept if the problem arose in the position is to phrase your answer like this:

> That is an excellent question, however I have never come across that scenario in my experiences, but I can explain how my thought process works to handle it in this hypothetical scenario. First, I would do ABC. Second, I would do XYZ while making sure DEF is done. Finally, HIJ would be completed allowing for the successful resolution of the issue. That is how I would handle the issue if it came up.

This shows honesty and that you are thinking on your feet. This is the better answer then just saying "I do not know."

Answer (score 0):

Think of it from the point of view of the interviewer, they are assessing how much support you would need, in the role they are interviewing for.

Giving one wrong, or partially inaccurate answer is not usually fatal. Likewise when they are exploring the edges of your knowledge, they will be expecting some "I don't know" answers.

Following up with multiple emails would be fatal. It would say to me this person is going to be a headache to manage.