# What to do if after a technical interview you realize the solution the interviewer pushed for is wrong?

Tags: interviewing

This is similar to:

[If you provided an incorrect answer to a technical question on an interview, should you respond with a corrected answer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9328/if-you-provided-an-incorrect-answer-to-a-technical-question-on-an-interview-sho)

but in this case, the solution I gave was one that the interviewer heavily hinted towards. Is it still a good idea to send an email to the interviewers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are saying that the interviewer was pushing you towards a certain answer which you gave, but afterward, you believe that the answer was incorrect?

Either the interviewer was deliberately pushing you to a wrong answer, in which case you fell for the subterfuge and it's too late, so there's nothing you can do, or the interviewer felt you gave the right answer, in which case there's nothing you *should* do.

Putting all that together, I would just suggest you let everything alone and see what happens.  While you *could* contact the interviewer if you truly believe that the hinted answer was incorrect, it probably wouldn't change much at this point.

Comment: added that generally interviewers don't push you toward the wrong answer, because why would they?

Comment: @bharal to see if you can think for yourself and are willing to go stand those in authority when they're just plain wrong?

Comment: @bharal Generally is the key. I have had it happen, and it was done on purpose. Fortunately I did not have to work with that person.

Comment: It wasn't immediately obvious at the time of the interview that the answer was wrong so if they were misleading me I don't think it was to see if I would reject an answer that was clearly wrong.I felt like the interviewers at this company were free to come up with their own questions and it felt like the interviewer was very proud of his solution which if it worked would've been very clever.

Comment: @ZhaiNan If the interviewer was proud of his solution and you gave it, then just let it go.  If you get the job, you can discuss with him why it was clever but wouldn't have worked :)

Comment: there is one more option: the interviewer is right, and you don't realize the constraints he gave. e.g. when he describes a problem and asks 'can you linearize it' (a typical question which i ask) it may be that the answer is wrong in general, but right in the special case.

Comment: @Sascha No doubt there are many variations on the above, but my advice remains unchanged: do nothing for now, and if they get the job they can discuss it at length with the interviewer.