# Call/email back interviewer for an alternative answer

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I recently had a telephonic interview with one of the future colleagues of mine. He had asked me some questions and I had answered them pretty much.

After the call when I was introspecting I realized there were alternative answers/different approaches to some questions which were totally valid too.

**Is it professional to email/call them about the alternative answers to the questions which were asked later?**

Comment: Were the answers you gave incorrect?  Also, my "future colleague", does this imply that you already have a job offer, or is this "would be a colleague if I got a job offer?" Either way, I'd let it go, calling them back smacks of desperation and it sounds like you handled the questions in a reasonable way.

Comment: No, it wasn't incorrect and yes they offered me the role.

Comment: In that case, let it go and you can discuss in more detail with your colleague once you commence work :)

Comment: @JaneS yea, initially I had the same thoughts too but I was like "just in case". Anyway thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you provided an incorrect answer to a technical question on an interview, should you respond with a corrected answer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9328/if-you-provided-an-incorrect-answer-to-a-technical-question-on-an-interview-sho)

Comment: @gnat I was thinking of that one too, which was why I confirmed that the answers the OP gave weren't in fact incorrect, _and_ that the OP has a job offer in hand. Hence I don't see this is a duplicate :)

Comment: @gnat I didn't provide incorrect answers. I was discussing the alternatives present. Thank you, Jane, for the clarifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer:** If the answers you gave were correct, then there's no reason to worry.

As in the comments, you confirmed that you have an accepted job offer for the company and your answers were not incorrect. I wouldn't bother calling or emailing about this, you already have the job and it's something you can discuss further with your colleague once you commence work with the organization.

Let it go, and good luck when you start the new job!

Comment: *＋1*: *"I wouldn't bother calling or emailing about this, you already have the job..."* - The first rule of holes is, when you are in a hole, you stop digging and drop the shovel. Don't give them a reason to rescind the job offer.